# Why is $E([\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n})]^2) = \Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}E[((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n})^2]$ in this solution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm studying Wiener process (Brownian motion) with the book: Brzezniak, & Zastawniak. "*Basic Stochastic Processes*." Springer.
I don't understand the solution for one of the exercises in the book. I'll first present the preliminary definition written in the book.

> **Definition** Let $$0=t_0^n<t_1^n<\cdots<t_n^n=T,$$
>   where $$t_i^n={iT\over n},$$
>   be a partition of the interval $[0, T]$ into $n$ equal parts. We denote by $$\Delta_i^n W = W(t_{i+1}^n) - W(t_i^n)$$
>   the corresponding increments of the Wiener process $W(t)$.

Now here's the exercise that I'm stuck with.

> **Exercise 6.29**
>   Show that
>   $$\operatorname{lim}_{n\to\infty}\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}(\Delta_i^nW)^2 = T\quad \mathrm{in} \ L^2.$$

Here's the solution from the book.

> **Soltion**
>   Since the increments $\Delta_i^n W$ are independent and
>   $$E(\Delta_i^n W) = 0,\quad E((\Delta_i^n W)^2) = {T \over n}, \quad
> E((\Delta_i^n W)^4) = {3T^2 \over n^2},$$
>   it follows that
>   $$E([\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}(\Delta_i^n W)^2-T]^2) = E([\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n})]^2)$$
>   $$=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}E[((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n})^2]$$
>   $$=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}[E((\Delta_i^n W)^4) - {2T\over n}E((\Delta_i^n W)^2) + {T^2 \over n^2}]$$
>   $$=\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}[{3T^2\over n^2}-{2T^2\over n^2}+{T^2\over n^2}]={2T^2\over n}\to 0$$
>   as $n\to\infty$.

I don't get the part $E([\Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n})]^2) = \Sigma_{i=0}^{n-1}E[((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n})^2]$ in the solution. How does a square of a sum becomes a sum of squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right)\right]^2&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathsf{E}\left((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right)\left((\Delta_j^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathsf{E}\left((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right)^2 \\
&\quad+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j\ne i}\mathsf{E}\left((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right)\mathsf{E}\left((\Delta_j^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right) \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathsf{E}\left((\Delta_i^nW)^2-{T\over n}\right)^2 
\end{align}
because the increments of $W$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{X_1,X_2,\cdots, X_n\}$ is a collection of independent random variables then variance of $\sum X_i =\sum var (X_i)$.